# Simple Selection Sort won't sort

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I'm new to algorithms and I tried to write a selection sort. With some help from the internet I have a script that *should* work, but doesn't. The result after the sort method is a list that is still unsorted.

I'm not sure if I missed anything and my code looks the same as the ones online.

Product.cs

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Order.cs

```
    public class Order
    {
        public List<Product> listOfProducts = new List<Product>(){
            new Product(){ Name="Item1", Price=2.55 },
            new Product(){ Name="Item2", Price=1.92 },
            new Product(){ Name="Item3", Price=2.12 }
        };

        public List<Product> GetAllProducts(){

            return this.listOfProducts;

        }

    
        public void SortProductsByPrice(){
                int min = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < this.listOfProducts.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    min = i;
                    for (int j = 0; j < this.listOfProducts.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (listOfProducts[j].Price < listOfProducts[min].Price)
                        {
                            min = j;
                        }
                    }
    
                    Product temporary = listOfProducts[min];
                    listOfProducts[min] = listOfProducts[i];
                    listOfProducts[i] = temporary;
                }
        }
    
    }
```

Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Order order = new Order();

            // unsorted list
            foreach (Product pro in order.GetAllProducts())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pro.Price);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");
            order.SortProductsByPrice();

            // sorted list
            foreach (Product pro in order.GetAllProducts())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pro.Price);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: This would be a good opportunity to learn how to use the debugger https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022, so you can step through code and check the value of your variables as you step through the code. Also, `listOfProducts` should not be public, and instead of defining a getter you can use `public IReadOnlyList<Product> ListOfProducts => listOfProducts;`

Comment: order.GetAllProducts().OrderBy(p => p.YourPropertyName)

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasAziz my guess is that this is for an algorithms class, and he is needing to go through the exercise of creating a sorter. If not for a class, then yes there are definitely better ways to sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is in the nested loop.

If you take a closer look at the [algorithm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/selection_sort_algorithm.htm), you'll see that:

> Selection sort is a simple sorting algorithm. This sorting algorithm is an in-place comparison-based algorithm in which the list is divided into **two parts**, **the sorted part at the left** end and **the unsorted part at the right end**. Initially, the sorted part is empty and the unsorted part is the entire list.

You're re-comparing your values with what you've already sorted, which you should not do. You're not getting a sorted list because by the end of your code, the values are being swapped over and over until they get back to their original order. A simple fix is by changing the nested for loop like this:

```
public void SortProductsByPrice()
{
    int min = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.listOfProducts.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < this.listOfProducts.Count; j++)
        {
            if (listOfProducts[j].Price < listOfProducts[min].Price)
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }

        Product temporary = listOfProducts[min];
        listOfProducts[min] = listOfProducts[i];
        listOfProducts[i] = temporary;
    }
}
```

So precisely, we just changed 1 line:

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < this.listOfProducts.Count; j++)  
             ^^^^^
```

If you take another look at the pseudo-code in the above link, you'll see that this function now resembles it:

```
procedure selection sort 
    list  : array of items
    n     : size of list

    for i = 1 to n - 1
        /* set current element as minimum*/
        min = i    
  
        /* check the element to be minimum */

        for j = i+1 to n 
            if list[j] < list[min] then
                min = j;
            end if
        end for

      /* swap the minimum element with the current element*/
        if indexMin != i  then
            swap list[min] and list[i]
        end if
    end for
    
end procedure
```

Comment: You've made a 2 char change: I'd just put the line you changed i.e. `for (int j = i+1; j < this.listOfProducts.Count; j++)` with some carets `^^^^` underlining the i+1

Comment: Aah thank you for the answer. At first it didn't make sense why the `i + 1` makes it work, but now it makes sense. That is what creates the division in the list for the sorted and unsorted parts.